# How to make two activities?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm new in Android studio and I'm trying to make two activities in my application but it don't works.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I think it's about the first options I put in my intent.

I'm new and I would like a simple solution or if you can explain me what I have to do it will be fine :)

This is my first activity (MainActivity):

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mPasserelle = null;
public final static String AGE = "com.myapplis.multiactivite.AGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPasserelle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.passerelle);
    mPasserelle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent secondeActivite = new Intent(MainActivity.this,IntentExample.class);
            secondeActivite.putExtra(AGE,24);
            startActivity(secondeActivite);
        }
    });

    }
}
```

The second activity(IntentExample) :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class IntentExample extends Activity{
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.seconde_activite);
    Intent i = getIntent();


    int age = i.getIntExtra(MainActivity.AGE,0);
    TextView resultat= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultat);
    resultat.setText("Le résultat est : "+age);

}
}
```

This is my first layout (activity_main), just a simple button to push to get the second activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.dunomade.multiactivite.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/passerelle"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

And now this is my second layout(seconde_activite), just a simple text to show me I'm on the second activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultat"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And to finish, this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapplis.multiactivite">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".IntentExample"
            android:label="seconde acivite">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I'm running the app, MainActivity is good, but when I try to click on the button the AVD show me "Have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest ?". I declared it on my manifest but I think the problem is in my MainActivity.

Please help me, I think for you it's really simple but I can't solve it, I tryed many way but I already got the same error.
Thank's for read and for answer =)

Comment: paste the whole logcat error, from here it seems good. `int age = i.getIntExtra(MainActivity.AGE);`

Comment: Do you get a log from the error? Seems strange to me.

Comment: Also, try `Build > Clean Project`

Comment: Clean and build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise that you use the name of package before the name of your activity, like this (some devices need this, like Moto G) :

```
<activity android:name="your.package.IntentExample "></activity>
```

And instead use:

```
public class IntentExample extends Activity
```

use:

```
public class IntentExample extends AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: I clean my project and I did what you say, it works fine. Thank you every body.

Comment: And can you explain me what's the difference between Activity and AppCompatActivity ?

Are the function name I have to call different ? If yes what they do different ?